# zeromq.js - Await connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, zeromq, publish-subscribe

The [documentation](http://zeromq.github.io/zeromq.js/classes/socket.html#connect) for `connect` method says,

> Connects to the socket at the given remote address and returns immediately. The connection will be made asynchronously in the background.

But, `await` does not seem to be applicable as shown in their example of subscriber code.

`subscriber.js`

```js
const zmq = require("zeromq")

async function run() {
  const sock = new zmq.Subscriber

  sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000") //Happens async; can we await this?
  sock.subscribe("kitty cats")
  console.log("Subscriber connected to port 3000")

  for await (const [topic, msg] of sock) {
    console.log("received a message related to:", topic, "containing message:", msg)
  }
}

run()
```

Also, what error(s) maybe raised by the `connect()` method? I provided an 'obscene' port number such as, `8124000`, to connect. I was hoping for some error messages to be raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"what error(s) maybe raised by the **`connect()`** method?"*

---

### The Error(s) part

The ZeroMQ native API distinguishes ( unchanged since v2.1 ) these errors for this :

> **`EINVAL`**
> The endpoint supplied is invalid.
> **`EPROTONOSUPPORT`**
> The requested transport protocol is not supported.
> **`ENOCOMPATPROTO`**
> The requested transport protocol is not compatible with the socket type.
> **`ETERM`**
> The ØMQ context associated with the specified socket was terminated.
> **`ENOTSOCK`**
> The provided socket was invalid.
> **`EMTHREAD`**
> No I/O thread is available to accomplish the task.

Yet your actual observer is dependent on the **`zeromq.js`** re-wrapping these principal states, so the best next step is to re-read the wrapper source code, so as to see, how these native API error states get actually handled inside the `zeromq.js`-wrapper.

The remarks :

> <sub>The following socket events can be generated. This list may be different depending on the ZeroMQ version that is used.
>
>
>
> Note that the ***error event is avoided by design***, since this has a special behaviour in `Node.js` causing an exception to be thrown if it is unhandled.
>
>
>
> Other ***error names*** are adjusted to be as close to possible as other networking related event names in Node.js and/or to the corresponding `ZeroMQ.js` method call. Events (including any errors) that correspond to a specific operation are namespaced with a colon :, e.g. **`bind:error`** or **`connect:retry`**.</sub>

are nevertheless quite warning, aren't they?

---

### The `await` part

The [MCVE-code <sub>( as-is )</sub>](https://tio.run/##XZA9T8MwEIZ3/4qTJ0cqSQoDUhBiZWdEDK57CW4T27EvjVrU3x7sfAgJefR7z/PeneRFBuW1owdjjzhNyppAcOt6eAWP/aA9Cn5Db7ueZ4zJcDUK6sEo0taAH4zI4IcBLHPBqnMcNDgmRP4xHBL8gJ7FSPrMY86gIsFJuaoo9o/PeRnfvnoqy5JnUBTwLp1DE2B2vYCSBkYEOUpNQN86vG2ssOEFP2uia4xSiC2XNrbFvLWN4H8tYLXjEciCs55g0aZ6tfWrRCzLfJJ1Wu2gC80X2Hp2Lsv@E3hUqC8RKqHDEGSD8XStXDQV38EK4nGKpDbaNFsw/UZ@6nxnd8bmg07TLw) is unable to reproduce the live-session, so best adapt the MCVE-code so as to get run-able and we can proceed further on this.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the project. I don't know why the code won't work; it is copy-pasted from here - http://zeromq.github.io/zeromq.js/index.html#pubsub